# Files transferring across PC when logging in

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, windows-domain

So I am looking at making my home PCs all linked to 1 server, I am doing this mainly as a project to better understand this sort of stuff, but one thing has always struck me as weird on how to do.

When I was at college we could log into any PC as long as it was on the same network, and it would bring up our user with everything in the exact same place, I am unsure if this is done via a DC and shared drives or what but could someone please elaborate on how this works? I would love to do this at home.
Also, can it be cross platform like Windows 10 and Windows 7? I expect it cant due to differences in the systems.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question can be pretty broad considering the amount of possible setups your college could have had to accomplish this so I will try to summarize some of the general points.

Also keep in mind that what you are looking to achieve is 100% possible and definitely encouraged if you are serious, but may be more involved than what you might be expecting. You may also start to get into the weeds in terms of financing some of the hardware and software that might make your experience easier. This is typically why these kinds of setups are limited to businesses and enterprises.

I work in enterprise infrastructure, however I am not an expert in any of these technologies, others might be able and more qualified to comment further.

**Imaging Software**

Allows administrators to flash a machine with a particular "image" i.e. a particular set of programs and settings. Typically you would have an image for various purposes (Professor's machines have a certain image, students have a certain image, particular departments might have different images with various software etc.)

**Software Distribution**

A popular option is an application like SCCM that allows windows administrators to push client packages to machines in a distribution group. This would allow you to go beyond imaging by maintaining machines images with updates and new software after they have been provisioned.

**Active Directory**

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746492(v=vs.85).aspx) might explain AD better than I can. Basically AD will allow you to setup user permissions and assign users to different user and computer groups. AD usually has its own dedicated infrastructure in a distributed system.

**Windows Domain**

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_domain) would again likely explain windows domains better than I can. A likely setup would have an admin domain, a student domain, a professor domain, etc. User profiles (all of your data) are saved within these domains. You would need at least one domain controller for your personal use.

**Windows Group Policy**

Windows Group Policy (GPO) is a profiling system that allows administrators to apply a set of settings across various machines in a particular domain or against a particular user

[This article](http://www.howtogeek.com/57729/how-to-make-windows-home-server-into-a-domain-controller/) should help you at least get started

Answer (score 0):

Your college was likely using Roaming Profiles - this is a feature of Windows that will allow you to log into different workstations and on logon it will copy your profile from a shared folder on a server on the network.  You can read this TechNet article on how to set it up:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649079(v=ws.11).aspx

Another useful feature you may find is Folder Redirection - this allows you to redirect your documents to a shared folder so it's easier to backup, etc...

Read about it here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732275(v=ws.11).aspx

Hope this helps.
John